Wordpress recommended plugins
I am developing a wordpress website for a client using Elementor. I am just wondering what other wordpress developers think are the primary basic essential plugins that should be installed on all client sites for a secure and fast website with all required funtionality?
Of course, I install rankmath or yoast for seo, and elementor to build the actual website iteself.
But, what other essential plugins are recommeded when making a website for a client?
I would be really interested to hear what other wordpress developers would recommend.

I have developed a WordPress theme for multiple organizations. I used various plugins based on the needs of the companies, but I only use the contact form plugin in all of them, which is my preferred choice: the Contact Form 7 plugin.

From my understanding choosing a plugin depends with what the website is intended to do. After outlining what the website functionality it becomes easier to choose a plugin for that. If it an eccommerce of course it will need Yeost and other recommended SEO plugins and other security plugins.

Thank you for your reply! Yoast definitely one I will use:)
